# TF2-Eigen 3.4 compatibility

Tags: c++, eigen, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working in a quite big project in ROS 1, Noetic. In this project, some code need Eigen 3.4.9. However, some other code needs tf2, including eigen conversions. When compiling with both of them, I have the same errors than compiling with Eigen 3.
Is there a way to make this work?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402594/tf2-eigen-3.4-compatibility/) by [Vic](https://answers.ros.org/users/68202/vic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2022-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Noetic targets Ubuntu Focal [which comes with Eigen 3.3.7](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/eigen3)

As you need Eigen 3.4.9 I would expect that to only add API elements and not have significant backwards breaking changes to the relatively simple elements of eigen that tf2 and eigen conversions takes advantage of. 3.4.0 is the default as of [jammy](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/jammy/eigen3)

To that end you should be able to install and use Eigen 3.4.9. There may be some minor tweaks that are needed to the code base, but as long as it stays in the 3 major version I would expect it to be generally compatible, but obviously it's not tested or supported so you'll be on your own to make it work.

**Note:** When you upgrade the version of Eigen any package that is building against it will need to be built from source on your system so that everything that you're using will be using a consistent version of Eigen. You should not use the binaries of anything that uses Eigen if you're upgrading it.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2022-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vic](https://answers.ros.org/users/68202/vic/) on 2022-06-20**:
Thanks for the answer. Are there any ressource on how to build from source on the system tf2?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2022-06-20**:
Here's how to install from source fully. http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Source You don't have to do everything, but anything that uses Eigen or depends on something that uses Eigen will have to be compiled from source. If you don't know how to select the packages well I'd strongly recommend just compiling everything to avoid the potentially complicated debugging of failiures.